# angular $http in service, return

Tags: angularjs

I have this in my factory

```
productsFactory.getOneProduct = function(){
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/products/' + $stateParams.productID
  }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config){

      console.log(data);
      return data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config){

    });
}
```

This is my controller:

```
$scope.selectedProduct = ProductsFactory.getOneProduct();
```

console.log(data) outputs the data i want. But I get 'undefined' when I call it from controller. Guess it got something to do with returning from anonymous functions? Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your `getOneProduct` function does not return anything which means it implicitly returns `undefined`, hence the error.

`$http` returns a promise and you must return that promise from your function. So change your code to this:

```
productsFactory.getOneProduct = function(){
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/products/' + $stateParams.productID
  }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config){

      console.log(data);
      return data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config){

    });
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
productsFactory
    .getOneProduct()
    .then(response){});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the `Promise` that is returned from `$http`:

```
productsFactory.getOneProduct = function(){
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/products/' + $stateParams.productID
  });
}
```

And then in your controller:

```
productsFactory.getOneProduct().then(successFunction, errorFunction);
```

You could simplify your factory call further:

```
 productsFactory.getOneProduct = function(){
      return $http.get('/api/products/' + $stateParams.productID);
    }
```

Comment: Thx. But exaclty what do i type in my controller? Tried this but I get undefined.     ProductsFactory.getOneProduct().then(function(d){
       $scope.selectedProduct = d;
    });

Comment: What is it that is undefined? the `$scope.selectedProduct`? or the `d`?